# Как перебрать массивы отличающиеся номером в названии?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массивы:

```
$array_8
$array_9
```

Их количество и номера могут быть разные. Номера хранятся в отдельном массиве $arr_id.

Пример $arr_id:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 9
)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то перебрать эти массивы не задавая им номер вручную?

Что-то вроде этого:

```
<?php foreach ($arr_id as $id) { ?>
<?php foreach ($array_"тут номер $id" as $value) { ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ипатьев как всегда глаголит истину. Но если возможности исправить данные нет, то можно сделать так:

```
foreach ($arr_id as $id) {
    foreach (${'array_' . $id} as $value) {
```

Подробнее [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), в блоке **Сложный (фигурный) синтаксис**.

Или так:

```
foreach ($arr_id as $id) {
    $arr_name = 'array_' . $id; 
    foreach ($$arr_name as $value) {
```

Подробнее о [переменных переменных](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: с `$$` нагляднее будет, имхо

Comment: Это уже третий вариант, добавил.

Comment: у вас все равно остался сложный синтаксис с фигурками, а не `$$`

Comment: Ну это просто уже какой-то кошмар)

Answer (score 5):

> Есть массивы:

Их не должно быть.

Должен быть **один** массив, элементами которого являются указанные массивы

```
Array
(
    [8] => [/* массив $array_8 */],
    [9] => [/* массив $array_9 */],
)
```

и уже этот массив перебирается с помощью обычного foreach()

Comment: может у человека уже имеются к примеру набор php-файлов, в каждом из которых определен некий `$array_X`. Так что должно не должно, но возможно таковы исходные данные.